# Is the partition count per broker decrease when decreasing number of replicas

Tags: apache-kafka

We have too many partitions per topic and we have a long way until we will have the time to attend the issue.
In the mean time we are trying to mitigate by decreasing the replication factor.
Will it affect the count per broker?

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing replica count will reduce the number of file-handles on the brokers, but it will not affect partition count of the topics.

Partitions cannot be reduced.